# Gparted Live: Can't resize ext4 partition

Tags: gparted

I'm running a VM with Centos 7 in a virtual environment (Proxmox). I'm out of space. So I've added some from Proxmox, booted from Gparted Live CD to allocate that space to /dev/sda2, but it won't let me resize. Please advice what can be done.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a swap partition between `/dev/sda2` and the free space. Turn off swap, remove the swap partition from `/etc/fstab`, then use Gparted to delete the swap partition `/dev/sda3` and the extended partition `/dev/sda4`; you will then be able to extend `/dev/sda2` in the adjacent free space.

Comment: Thank you. How do I "turn off swap and remove it from /etc/fstab"?

Comment: Turn off swap by running `swapoff -a` as root. To remove the swap from `/etc/fstab` use your favorite text editor -- comment out the line for the swap partition.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like a correct answer. I probably would be able to do it even when I'm booted from Gparted Liv CD, right?